# Python Email message not producing an output

Tags: python

I have to design a class Message that models an e-mail message. A message has a recipient, a sender, and a message text. Design your class to support the following methods:

1. A constructor that takes the sender and recipient as arguments,
2. append that takes one string argument and appends it to the message body as a new line,
3. **str** that makes the message into one long string like this: `"From: Harry Morgan\nTo: Rudolf Reindeer\n\nCome to the North Pole."`

My code is not producing an output, I have tried to change spacing. The code seems to be set up right to me. I am fairly new to coding so I could be missing something. Any help is appreciated!

This is my **Message.class**:

```
 class Message:

    def __init__(self, sender, recipient):

    self.sender = sender
    self.recipient = recipient
    self.body = ""

def append(self, line):

    self.body += line + "\n"

def toString(self):
    messageString = "From: {}\nTo: {}\n{}\n".format(self.sender, self.recipient, self.body)
    return messageString
```

Comment: What do you mean that your code is not producing an output? ```toString``` clearly returns a value.

Comment: how are creating the instances? how are calling toString method?

Comment: To add to the previous comment by Joshua, do you mean that it does not print anything? In that case, try `print(messageString)` instead of `return`.

Comment: It is suppose to produce an output of sending an email. For example: Who is sending the message: Who would you like to send the message to: Enter body (blank line to quit): Enter body (blank line to quit): Enter body (blank line to quit): 
FROM: Alice
TO: Professor Smith

Will you be available tomorrow at 9:30 AM?
I need help with my math homework.

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start, you've created a class, but nothing will happen until you actually instantiate the object.

I've made some modifications/comments to the end of your code, hopefully this helps you understand it a bit better!

```
class Message:

    def __init__(self, sender, recipient):
        self.sender = sender
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.body = ""

    def append(self, line):
        self.body += line + "\n"

    def toString(self):
        messageString = "From: {}\nTo: {}\n{}\n".format(self.sender, self.recipient, 
        self.body)
        return messageString


sender = input('Who is sending this message?')  #creating a string to pass to class

recipient = input('Who is receiving this message?') #same as above

body = input('What would you like to send?') #this is for your append method

email = Message(sender, recipient) #instantiating the class

email.append(body) #using your append method to add the body

print(email.toString()) #printing the results of your toString method(which I recommend renaming for clarity)
```